# Capture the click event on bootbpx confirm/alert box buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootbox

I am trying to create a plugin to capture all the click events on a page. These have confirm and alerts are shown using bootbox plugin. I would like to attach a click event to bootbox confirm/alert buttons (Ex: when clicking on Ok or Yes or No) so that I can capture the click event. I do not want to use bootbox callback events since I do not own the codebase to add the callback events and also I want a common place to capture the clicks.

[bootbox modal dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW4uC.png)

Since bootbox confirm/alert are created dynamically, I tried to attach the click event using jquery as below

```
$(document).on('click', ':button', function(){ 
    alert('bootbox button clicked');
});


$(document).on('click', 'button[type="button"]', function(){
   alert('bootbox button clicked');
});
```

also tried with class selector as well.

```
$(document).on('click', '.tempclass', function(){
   alert('bootbox button clicked');
});
```

tempclass is the class is assiggned to bootbox plugin.

I also tried with javascript attach events as below

```
document.addEventListener("click", handleClick, false);
document.attachEvent("onclick", handleClick);
function handleClick(event)
{
    alert('bootbox button clicked');
}
```

But, I was not successful. Every other dynamically created control's click events are getting fired except bootbox button click events. Can somebody please help me on this.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the build-in callback functionallity of the plugin, see the "Advanced Usage" sections:

http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html

Comment: Hi cyrix, I do not have the code base to add the callback functionality. I am writing a wrapper to capture the click events in a common place.

Comment: Did try to listen on custom events bootbox is firering like here: https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/blob/master/bootbox.js#L697

Comment: Is it possible to create a global callback function for alert/confirm/dialog of bootbox?